# the meaning of the phrase "on the property"

Tags: phrase-usage

just don't quite understand "on the property" in"His hobby also led a Hawaii golf course to relocate an Army couple’s wedding to another site on the property for security purposes."

is "on the property" a set phrase? and what's the meaning?

Comment: "Property" means the land owned by the golf course.  Here, "on the property" just means somewhere on the land owned by the golf course.  In the larger context of the sentence, the wedding was moved from one part of the land owned by the golf course to another part.

Comment: In English, we capitalize the first word in each sentence.